# How can i calculate Covariance between numeric attributes and Binary attributes?

Tags: correlation, feature-selection, covariance, binary-data

I want to calculate covariance between binary attribute and numeric attribute For example: if x is numeric attribute, y is binary attribute. Then how can i calculate cov(x,y)?[image]

Comment: The recipe isn’t different because one or even both variables are binary.